# Create a TikZ overlay with RH mirror of LH

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, shading

Thanks to [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo) in [this question ("Clip an A3 tikz overlay to two A4 pages")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347152), I managed to create a background in two halves for use on two consecutive pages.

Now I need to create symmetrical one in which the LH side is a mirror of the RH side, eg
[image: Gradated symmetrical background]

This is for a whole landscape page, so should I do this as two separate pictures, or is there a way to create it all in one go?

Comment: Two separate tikzpictures would be easier.  Note you can also use negative scales with \includegraphics and \scalebox.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `pdf` file with background, you can mirror it with:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west] at (current page.north west)
{\includegraphics[width=.5\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west, xscale=-1] at (current page.north east)
{\includegraphics[width=.5\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you have a `tikxpicture`, you can mirror it with a `shifted` and `scaled` `scope`. In this case you can apply different options to the mirrored picture.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]

\begin{scope}[shift=(current page.south west)]
\draw[line width=2mm, red] (0,0)--++(.5\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift=(current page.south east), xscale=-1]
\draw[line width=2mm, green] (0,0)--++(.5\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's TikZ, as in the post I linked above. Thanks very much, I'll try to apply that.

Comment: I have managed to make some of this work on the help given above, thank you very much.