# I am trying to import a picture

Tags: book-design

I am trying to make a cover for a book. I have successfully imported the picture I wanted into my document, but can't seem to get the formatting right. I want the picture to cover the entire page. Any suggestions would be helpful. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=16cm,height=\paperheight]{E:/TEX/TestingPro/Physics/Kinematics/book_cover}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Maybe [Insert a full page image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136900/124842) could be useful...

Comment: One solution not previously mentioned is to use tikz.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236949/how-to-change-the-background-color-within-a-page and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363957/position-a-tikz-background-pattern-which-is-oversize-to-bleed-off-the-edge-of-t for example.