# control black color only in gradient by using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, gradient, cmyk

My code follows:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\input colordvi
\input cmyk-hax
\makeatletter
\definecolor{testcolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}
\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{testcolor}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[testcolor]{ball}{\pgfqpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(testcolor!15!white);
 color(9bp)=(testcolor!75!white);
 color(18bp)=(testcolor!70!black);
 color(25bp)=(testcolor!50!black);
 color(50bp)=(black)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hspace*{-1pc}\vbox{
\begin{centering}
\newlength\radius
\pgfmathsetlength{\radius}{0.25cm}
\newcommand\drawballs[2][]{%
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \yy using #2+1-\y] in {1,...,#2} {%
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\yy} {%
            \shade[shading=ball,ball color=white,#1]
                ({(2*\x-2+\y)*\radius},{sqrt(3)*\y*\radius}) circle (\radius);
        };
    }%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
%    \drawballs{1}
%    \drawballs[xshift=1.5cm]{2}
%    \drawballs[xshift=4cm]{3}
%    \drawballs[xshift=7cm]{4}
%    \drawballs[xshift=10cm]{5}
    \drawballs[xshift=2cm]{1}
    \drawballs[xshift=3.5cm]{2}
    \drawballs[xshift=5.5cm]{3}
    \drawballs[xshift=8cm]{4}
    \drawballs[xshift=11cm]{5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{centering}
}


\end{document}
```

This code works well and the output generated successfully. But shaded part shows the mixing color of `CMYK` combination, but my requirement shade variation should show only `B/W`. Kindly suggest how can achieve this?

Comment: Maybe with `\definecolor{testcolor}{gray}{0.9}` if I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @MaxSnippe Thanks for your quick suggestion, but still the problem exists....

Comment: What then is exactly your problem?

Comment: Well, @MaxSnippe tried to politely tell you that your question is not as clear as it could (or even should) be. Could you please try to make a more precise version?

Comment: I think this is because `pgf` gradients do not support CMYK. They get converted to RGB, which messes everything up.

Comment: Perhaps a technique similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389466/87678 could be used. But I'm not familiar enough with `pgfplots` to do it.

Answer (score 4):

## Update

`tikz` now supports grayscale and CMYK shadings since version 3.1.3. So it is only necessary to use `\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}` (or `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}`) before loading `tikz`.

---

The fundamental problem is that `pgf` shadings do not support CMYK. So even though you define your `testcolor` colour in CMYK, it gets converted to RGB in the radial shading in your spheres.

Then when you try to output separations, you find that the RGB gray separates out onto all four plates instead of just the black plate.

This can be solved using a new package, `pgf-cmykshadings`, which supports CMYK (and grayscale) shadings.

Change the start of your MWE to:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}% (could also use \usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor})
\usepackage{cmyk-shadings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\input colordvi
\input cmyk-hax
```

`pgf-cmykshadings` will work with all LaTeX engines, so if you don't need `cmyk-hax`, you could drop it (and `colordiv`) and use `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex`.

This will result in a PostScript (or PDF) file which only uses the black plate.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, will check and get back to you, hence I'm in traveling ...